# Reading hiddenFile value in code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have `<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenListFiled" runat="server" Value="" />` in my .aspx page , in which  i include java script file.

```
  <script language="javascript" src="includes/multifile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my multifile.js file i am setting the value of hiddenFild  as below

```
listofslected = listofslected +"///" + e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
var listofdocts =  document.getElementById('hiddenListFiled');     listofdocts.value= listofslected
```

Now, i want to read the value of hiddenListFiled in behind the code. but its giving me "hiddenListFiled" not define .

So I try to createElement of type=hidden in Multifile.js itself and try to read that its saying me element not found.

Could you please suggest me how i will get value of hiddenfile in behind the code? I already tried `Request.Form["hiddenListFiled"]` no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [ClientIDMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)'s value to Static so that ASP.Net does not rename it:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenListFiled" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value="" />
```